# How to retrieve the different results of a regex (using grep?) into variables?

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, regular-expression, variable

**Question in short**

Given a string, how to retrieve several sub-strings given a regex?

```
echo "hello world 15 42" | grep -P ".*([0-9]+) ([0-9]+)";
```

This unfortunately return the full matching string, not the 15 and 42 separately. Ideally some variable would recover both of them so I could use them:

```
echo "First: $0, Second: $1"; # echo is only an example
```

**More of the context**

For an install script, it needs to download the relevant file from an URL (with wget), however, the specific file name is unknown, so the script need to first download the index.html to extract file-names, extract the version numbers and re-construct the full URL.

```
wget 2>/dev/null -O - http://...../directory/ | grep -P "<a href=....
wget "http://..../directory/file-$1-revision-$2.gz" -O downloaded.gz
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use bash regex matching and access the builtin BASH_REMATCH array

```
s="hello world 15 42"
re='.*([0-9]+) ([0-9-]+)'
if [[ $s =~ $re ]]; then
    for key in "${!BASH_REMATCH[@]}"; do 
        printf "%s\t%s\n" "$key" "${BASH_REMATCH[$key]}"
    done
fi
```

```
0   hello world 15 42
1   5
2   42
```

Comment: Why is the `BASH_REMATCH[$key]` printing `5` and not `15`?

Comment: I learn a lot understanding this code, thanks you. It worked.

Comment: Because `.*` is greedy. Some of the other answers here have adjusted the regex

Answer (score 2):

```
> greparray=($(echo "hello world 15 42" | grep -Eo "[0-9]+ [0-9]+"))
> echo ${greparray[1]}
42
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use an array:

```
myArray=($(echo "hello world 15 42" | egrep -o '([0-9]+)'))
```

Access the first substring:

```
echo ${myArray[0]}
15
```

...and the second:

```
echo ${myArray[1]}
42
```

Comment: In this case, where the results are on separate lines, I'd use `mapfile -t myArray < <(echo ... | egrep -Eo ...)`

Comment: It does not really answer the question: you don't get the values of the regex, but changed the regex for matching several substring. If (for instance) you add a string between ***hello*** and ***world***, myArray would contain 3 values and the result would be wrong.

Comment: Do feel free to adapt the regex in whatever way suits your purpose best. The array method works with the original regex as well. Best regards!

Comment: The problem is: myArray[n] is not related with the capture parenthesis. Try `myArray=($(echo "hello wonderful world 15 42" | egrep -o ".*([0-9]+) ([0-9]+)")); echo ${myArray[3]}`, or `myArray=($(echo "hello world 15 42" | egrep -o ".*([0-9]+) ([0-9]+)")); echo ${myArray[3]}` You get 15 or 42 depending on the starting string.

Comment: @AdrianMaire Umm... sorry, you've lost me. Apparently I have completely misunderstood the question.